# DataTables-Auto Scroll

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

> Hi Everyone, I bind the model into my data tables with a scrollbar. But My scrollbar can't scroll automatically. It's scroll manually. I need to change my data table only to scroll from top to bottom. how to write the code. My sample is below mentioned.

> JavaScript:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    scrollResize: true,
    scrollY: 100,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging: false
} );
```

> HTML

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

> My Output:
> [DataTable_Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZtLV.png)